# Plotting in Octave on MaxOS X

Tags: macos, plot, gnuplot, octave, fltk

I'm trying to work with Octave on Mac OS X 10.9.2 and I'm having problems plotting. I found that running

```
setenv('GNUTERM','qt')
```

solves the problem momentarily, but I get the following error when I try to plot after running some code:

```
warning: get: some elements in list of return values are undefined
warning: get: some elements in list of return values are undefined
warning: get: some elements in list of return values are undefined
warning: get: some elements in list of return values are undefined
warning: get: some elements in list of return values are undefined
warning: get: some elements in list of return values are undefined
warning: get: some elements in list of return values are undefined
warning: get: some elements in list of return values are undefined
warning: get: some elements in list of return values are undefined
warning: get: some elements in list of return values are undefined
warning: get: some elements in list of return values are undefined
warning: get: some elements in list of return values are undefined
warning: get: some elements in list of return values are undefined
warning: get: some elements in list of return values are undefined
warning: get: some elements in list of return values are undefined
warning: get: some elements in list of return values are undefined
warning: get: some elements in list of return values are undefined
warning: get: some elements in list of return values are undefined
warning: get: some elements in list of return values are undefined
warning: get: some elements in list of return values are undefined
warning: get: some elements in list of return values are undefined
warning: get: some elements in list of return values are undefined
warning: get: some elements in list of return values are undefined
warning: get: some elements in list of return values are undefined
warning: get: some elements in list of return values are undefined
warning: get: some elements in list of return values are undefined
warning: get: some elements in list of return values are undefined
warning: get: some elements in list of return values are undefined
warning: get: some elements in list of return values are undefined
warning: get: some elements in list of return values are undefined
warning: get: some elements in list of return values are undefined
warning: get: some elements in list of return values are undefined
warning: get: some elements in list of return values are undefined
warning: get: some elements in list of return values are undefined
warning: get: some elements in list of return values are undefined
error: __next_line_style__: A(I): index out of bounds; value 1 out of bound 0
error: called from:
error:   /usr/local/octave/3.8.0/share/octave/3.8.0/m/plot/util/__next_line_style__.m at line 42, column 5
error:   /usr/local/octave/3.8.0/share/octave/3.8.0/m/plot/draw/private/__plt__.m at line 489, column 3
error:   /usr/local/octave/3.8.0/share/octave/3.8.0/m/plot/draw/private/__plt__.m at line 242, column 5
error:   /usr/local/octave/3.8.0/share/octave/3.8.0/m/plot/draw/private/__plt__.m at line -1, column -1
error:   /usr/local/octave/3.8.0/share/octave/3.8.0/m/plot/draw/private/__plt__.m at line -1, column -1
error:   /usr/local/octave/3.8.0/share/octave/3.8.0/m/plot/draw/plot.m at line 215, column 3
warning: get: some elements in list of return values are undefined
warning: get: some elements in list of return values are undefined
warning: get: some elements in list of return values are undefined
gnuplot_set_term: not a figure handle
warning: get: some elements in list of return values are undefined
warning: implicit conversion from matrix to sq_string
error: __go_draw_figure__: expecting figure object, found ''
error: called from:
error:   /usr/local/octave/3.8.0/share/octave/3.8.0/m/plot/util/private/__go_draw_figure__.m at line -1, column -1
error:   /usr/local/octave/3.8.0/share/octave/3.8.0/m/plot/util/__gnuplot_drawnow__.m at line -1, column -1
```

I installed the fltk toolkit and tried running

```
graphics_toolkit("fltk")
```

but I got the following error:

```
error: __init_fltk__: not available without OpenGL and FLTK libraries
error: called from:
error:   /usr/local/octave/3.8.0/share/octave/3.8.0/m/plot/util/graphics_toolkit.m at line 69, column 3
```